# Do mortar strikes cause friendly fire?

Tags: battlefield-3

In *Battlefield 3*, (*non*-hardcore) I know that grenades can damage both enemies and teammates.  Does this also apply to mortar fire?  Am I hurting my own team with splash damage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you aren't. Not physically, at least. If one of your mortar rounds lands close to a teammate (in non-hardcore), your teammate won't take any damage. It DOES cause their screen to shake horribly, which can be harmful if they're currently in a gunfight, as it throws off their accuracy and leaves them vulnerable to enemy fire without the ability to return fire easily. It only lasts for a couple of seconds though.

One thing worth noting, however, is this: If your mortars strike a friendly target as he is laying C4 or AT Mines, the mortar will cause these to detonate, possibly resulting in a suicide for your teammate.

Comment: I would presume it could kill them indirectly if they had places Mines, c4, etc and your mortar blew them up. But I haven't tested this

Comment: That's true. I've been hit by a friendly mortar as I was setting AT Mines. It blew my mines up, causing me to Suicide...

Comment: Maybe you should edit you question to reflect that then.

Comment: yep, very good to point out the "blowing up explosives near teammates can cause them to get killed" part of this -- it's the only edge condition in friendly fire OFF

Comment: @JeffAtwood Indeed. I dunno how many times I've been placing AT mines in front of a tank only to have a teammate shoot the tank and blow my mines (and me) up.